# Would a regular expression be best for this problem?

Tags: php, regex

I need to take a url like this:

> https://www.domain.com/m/281/[imagename].jpg

and turn it into this:

> http://www.NEWdomain.com/images/[imagename].jpg

I will need to do this to many urls so I want to write a quick php script to put the urls in array and then loop to change the domain name and remove the file structure in the original urls.  Not all the original urls are `/m/281`  some are slightly different.

I thought I could do a `str_replace` for the `https://www.domain.com` to `http://www.NEWdomain.com`, but I am stumped with how to change the varying `/m/281/` in the url's to my file structure like `/images/`.

Would a regular expression be best to solve this problem?

Comment: Two questions that should affect the 'right' solution: 1. When you say that /m/281/ varies, do you mean that it is always a letter followed by three numbers, separated by slashes? Or does that structure itself change? 2. Is it a one-off script or something that needs to run continuously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change all image urls from all paths, this tested function should do the trick.

```
function fixurls($text) {
    $re = '% # Match image urls in domain.com
        https://www\.domain\.com/ # Required domain.
        (?:[^\s/]+/)*             # Optional pathname.
        ([^\s/]+\.jpe?g|png|gif)  # $1: Filename (images only)
        \b                        # Anchor to word boundary.
        %xim';
    // Fix all image URLs in $text string.
    $replace = 'http://www.NEWdomain.com/images/$1';
    $text = preg_replace($re, $replace, $text);
    return $text;
}
```

You can easily modify the path portion of the regex if you only wish to change images from specific paths.

Comment: This worked fantastically thanks!  I'm sure the other suggestions would have worked as well.  But this solved my problem fast... Thanks so much. I'll have to save that now for future use.

Answer (score 3):

you could try something like :

1. strip off the "https://"
2. do a str_replace() as you said on
   the domain
3. split the string into an array based
   on "/". `explode("/", $urlString);`
4. loop through and remove any elements
   after the URL element but not the
   last.

result will be:

```
$arr[0] = www.NEWdomain.com
$arr[1] = [imagename].jpg
```

then just insert before the last element "images"

result will then be:

```
$arr[0] = www.NEWdomain.com
$arr[1] = images
$arr[2] = [imagename].jpg
```

finally implode it back to a string:

```
$blah = implode("/", $arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try using some URL parsing library like - [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

and then get each component and do simpler string replace perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression could match `/[a-zA-Z]/[0-9]*/`, if I didn't make a bad assumption about your old pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is `preg_replace()`.

Answer (score 0):

If only the first two subdirectory segments are variable, you could try:

```
$src = preg_replace(
   "~https?://www.domain.com/\w+/\d+/(.*?\.jpg)~"    // match regex
   "http://www.NEWdomain.com/images/$1",           // replacement
   $src);
```

The `\w` means a letter, and `\d+` matches decimals. The `.*?` works on almost anything, since you didn't give any criteria for the filename.

In the replacement string the `$1` just becomes what was previously matched with the `(` capture `)` parens.