# preg_match question

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

i have this preg_match rule:

```
preg_match( '#(http:\/\/(www.)?imgur.com)\/(gallery\/)?(([-|~_0-9A-Za-z]+)&?.*?)#i', $link, $matches )
```

this match for

```
http://imgur.com/xxxx
http://www.imgur.com/xxxx
http://imgur.com/gallery/xxxx
```

how i can avoid to match with `imgur.com/a/xxxx#xxxx` ?

Comment: What exactly should not be matched? `/a/` ? `#xxxx` ? Both? Only together or independently?

Comment: will match all before just avoid /a/

Comment: Are you matching the string or trying to find it in another string? It would seem the former...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you want:

```
preg_match( '#(http:\/\/(www.)?imgur.com)\/(?!a)(gallery\/)?(([-|~_0-9A-Za-z]+)&?.*?)#i', $link, $matches )
```

With this url like `http://imgur.com/a/xxxxxx` won't match.

PS: Though depending on what you are doing, I think that the regular expression may get unnecessarily complicated and you should try to find simpler methods. Look at my answer here regarding parsing urls: [Would a regular expression be best for this problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697516/would-a-regular-expression-be-best-for-this-problem/5697534#5697534)

Answer (score 0):

You could detect the URLs and then pass them to `parse_url()` where you could unset them from your matches if they contain that path.

Will probably be easier to read :)